# Question closed as a duplicate - points instead of two shapefiles

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

The question that I posted some months ago was closed as a duplicate.

[Point dataset from CSV showing up outside of known region](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/364473/point-dataset-from-csv-showing-up-outside-of-known-region/)

The duplicate that moderators tagged is listed here:

[Adjusting extents so that same-CRS shapefiles overlap in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140900/adjusting-extents-so-that-same-crs-shapefiles-overlap-in-qgis)

The question that I posted is not a duplicate since the duplicate deals with two different shapefiles and projections.  My question is associated with points in QGIS and might be useful for people searching for a solution that involves points and not a shapefile.  Can someone review this?

Comment: Not sure why 4 users deemed it a duplicate, different data, have re-opened.

Comment: @Mapperz this will help so that users can find the solution when there is different data.  Thanks.

Comment: There are some overzealous users and moderators here, like on Wikipedia, that prefer to close things instead of understanding their peculiarities. Don't let that discourage you :)

Comment: @bugmenot123 I will definitely continue to post. Thanks for the encouragement and the clarifying information.

Answer (score 2):

Question reopened by @Mapperz per comment:

> Not sure why 4 users deemed it a duplicate, different data, have
> re-opened.